# Jquery Get date range of quarter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to think of the best way to accomplish this little task I am trying to complete.

I am going to have 2 drop downs, one for Year and one for Quarter.

The year is going to show Current year + the next year.

The quarter drop down will just show Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4

When I pick Q2 of 2014 i want to be able to say "Here is the date range" April 1st, 2014 - June 30th, 2014.

I found that this is how to figure out the quarters of the year:

```
var today = new Date();
var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
```

Just not sure on a simple way to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the start and end dates of a given quarter:

```
var year = 2014;
var quarter = 1;
var start = new Date(year,quarter*3-3,1);
var end = new Date(year,quarter*3,0);
```

You can then format the dates as you want.